# ORDER BY inside Decode Oracle Function

Tags: oracle

I try to use ORDER BY inside the Oracle Decode function

The compiler says missing right parenthesis

```
DECODE(controlNumber, NULL, myOldNUmber, (SELECT myNewNumber FROM tableA A, tableB B WHERE A.control_id = B.control_id AND A.other_id = B.other_id) ) AS finalnumber,
```

Seems it is the same query did not see why the `ORDER BY` is not accepted here:

```
DECODE(controlNumber, NULL, myOldNUmber, (SELECT myNewNumber FROM tableA A, tableB B WHERE A.control_id = B.control_id AND A.other_id = B.other_id ORDER BY createdTime)) AS finalnumber,
```

Comment: Why do you need the ORDER BY ? You can use ony a `scalar subqury` as the argument of the function. Scalar subquery is a query which can return at most 1 row. So why do you need to order 1 row ?

Comment: I have many services stored on my table and i need the last service executed and recorded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to test currently, but please try...

```
DECODE(controlNumber, NULL, myOldNUmber, (SELECT myNewNumber FROM (SELECT myNewNumber FROM tableA A, tableB B WHERE A.control_id = B.control_id AND A.other_id = B.other_id ORDER BY createdTime) WHERE rownum=1) AS finalnumber
```

Comment: Great ! i will test.

Comment: Can not access tableB inside the inner subselect maybe because i am doing it into a two tables UNION

Comment: Any other Inner query works i just can not access tableB into the Inner query